# How to define and use a funciton outside a class?

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, linked-list, singly-linked-list

In the following code for linked list implementation in Python3. How do I define and call the functions such as reverse() and display() outside of the class. Like, how should create a function that performs operations like display() and recerse(). How should I pass a LinkedList object and how to access its members, so that I am able to do desired operations?

PS : I removed other functions because I was not able to post this question.
I am **not** asking about importing the class file to use in other .py files.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def display(self):
        curr = self.head
        while curr != None:
            print(curr.data + '->', end = ' ')
            curr = curr.next
        print('NULL')
    def append(self, data):
    '''
    statements....
    '''
    def length(self):
        ptr = self.head
        count = 0
        while ptr.next != None:
            count += 1
            ptr = ptr.next
        print(count+1)

    def reverse(self):
        pre = None
        cur = self.head
        while cur != None:
            temp = cur.next
            cur.next = pre
            pre = cur
            cur = temp
        self.head = pre
        self.display()

l = LinkedList()
l.append('A')
l.append('B')
l.append('C')
l.append('D')
l.prepend('E')
l.display()
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure I'm understanding your question correctly, but if I am it seems that you just want to take all of the code, minus the program code (from "l=LinkedList()" down in your example), and save it to a python file, then at the top of any python code you need to use your class in, import your file.

If your class file is not in the same directory as the code from which you wish to use the class, you'll need to keep the class file in a directory in your path:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

and if you wish to add a directory to your path, you can:

```
sys.path.append('<directory')
```

At that point, once you

```
import LinkedList
```

(assuming your class file is called LinkedList.py) you'll be able to define variables using your class and use it the same as you would in your example, so your code file would look something like:

```
import LinkedList

l = LinkedList()
l.append('A')
l.append('B')
l.append('C')
l.append('D')
l.prepend('E')
l.display()
```

Or am I just not reading your question correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I added the prepend and append method for you, I'm not sure if this is what you were referring to. Also, if you're looking for static vs class methods, you can check those out here: [Class method vs static method in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/class-method-vs-static-method-python/)

With static methods you can return instances of a specified class by using arguments to the static method. **Check out the link above to use class functions outside of their instances.**

Here is the Python code:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def display(self):
        curr = self.head
        while curr != None:
            print(curr.data + '->', end = ' ')
            curr = curr.next
        print('NULL')

    def append(self, data):
        data_node = Node(data)
        data_node.next = self.head
        self.head = data_node

    def prepend(self, data):
        ptr = self.head
        while ptr.next != None:
            ptr = ptr.next
        ptr.next = Node(data)

    def length(self):
        ptr = self.head
        count = 0
        while ptr.next != None:
            count += 1
            ptr = ptr.next
        print(count+1)

    def reverse(self):
        pre = None
        cur = self.head
        while cur != None:
            temp = cur.next
            cur.next = pre
            pre = cur
            cur = temp
        self.head = pre
        self.display()

l = LinkedList()
l.append('A')
l.append('B')
l.append('C')
l.append('D')
l.prepend('E')
l.display()
```

Comment: Im sorry, but no this is not what I asked .  What I meant is instead of defining the function inside the LinkedList class, I want to define it outside the class. But how do I do that.?

Comment: Could you give me an example of how you imagine calling the function and creating the nodes? Like if you had your best case scenario, what would your code look like?